# Do fish hooks have a lead coating?

Tags: fishing-tackle

I recently read the following: "It's very important to remove the hook before cooking and eating the fish.... If you cook the hook, the layer of lead that coats the hook will melt into the fish..."  (https://www.wikihow.com/Unhook-a-Fish)

I'm familiar with lead in weights and solder joints, but do hooks often contain a lead *coating* as well?

Thanks!

edit: I ask this because, for ecological and child-safety reasons, I avoid tackle containing lead.  I'd like to know if I should investigate my plain old j-hooks more closely.

I have no intention to cook a fish with the hook in :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is **not** common for hooks to have a lead coating, at least in my locale (US southwest). They are most often brass, steel with a brass plating, plain steel, or stainless steel.

Brass may have varying percentage of lead content... but that is a small percentage.

Answer (score 3):

Some hooks have a lead weight moulded into the shank.

You would not eat that easily but why do you care when the other danger is putting the hook through your own lip while eating the fish?

There is also the fact that hooks are usually re-usable. Another day, another fish.

A similar – but more serious – danger is when eating [**game** killed with a shotgun](https://www.food.gov.uk/safety-hygiene/lead-shot-game). It's not so obvious, because you don't want the lead shot back for re-use.

Comment: thanks for the response.  For clarification, I'm not interested in cooking a fish with the hook still in.  I just want to know whether it's common for hooks to have a lead coating.

Answer (score 0):

No.Probably many decades ago before chrome plating and stainless steel , hard steel hooks may have been tin plated . Because tin melts at low temperature some one mistook it for lead.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking that is an idiotic statement in that wiki.  Having said that, coatings theses days can be made out of all sorts of exotic materials, but even if the coating did contain lead its unlikely to have enough of it for it to be dangerous